# How to use intent in android 7 (api 24)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-7.0-nougat

I have some code working good in api < 24 but in api 24 it's not working and crashes the app.
code:

```
File root = new File(path);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(root);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
startActivity(intent);
```

So how to use intent in android >= 7 (api >= 24)?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed

Answer (score 0):

Try this to switch from an Activity to another using intent:

```
Intent int = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActActivity.class);
startActivity(int);
```

Comment: [Is it ok to write "hope that helps" or why is my answer being edited (duplicate)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258187/6045800)